# I am getting the same error everytime I try to boot Ubuntu on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

Every time I try to run Ubuntu, this error comes up.

```
"Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Linux.

The virtual machine 'Linux' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).  More details may be available in 'C:\Users\matthew\VirtualBox VMs\Linux\Logs\VBoxStartup.log'.

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: Machine
Interface: IMachine {480cf695-2d8d-4256-9c7c-cce4184fa048}"
```

I do not know why, I have the .iso file n my desktop, and connected to the IDE Secondary Master. It just isn't making any sense, I am very angered at this because I have been trying to boot Ubuntu so I can manually root my phone. But, I have obviously hit a major road block. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you look at the log file?  Anyway, this sounds like a virtualbox problem, rather than a Ubuntu problem, since you apparently are not able to even access the Ubuntu image file.  It seems like you'd be better off creating a CD or USB boot device, and not messing with a virtual machine.

Comment: Well, thanks. I only have one computer to use, and I must do this without restarting my computer to keep it from taking to long. Well, thanks for the help.

Comment: Make sure you have installed the headers for your linux kernel. Maybe even check if the correct dkms vbox modules are present.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem occurred when running the VM with `VBoxManage`, and the fix was that I had forgotten to specify `--type headless` on the command line.

Answer (score -1):

You Must Install [Virtual Box 4.0](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.0.26/VirtualBox-4.0.26-95035-Win.exe)

Comment: You have linked to windows version of Virtual-Box `.exe`!! and it's good to make this as comment instead of answer.

Comment: @KasiyA I believe that the questioner is attempting to load Ubuntu as guest on Windows as Host - there should be more explanation as to the 'why' of the answer though, as in Why VirtualBox 4.0 instead of VirtualBox 4.3.20

Comment: @CharlesGreen uh. I see in OP's error logs. yes you are right, OP is on windows.